# How to force merge two remote branches locally?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-remote

I'm trying to merge my local branch from a different repository to my upstream code. I would like to merge `priv/dev` branch to `origin/master` in my development system. I want to prioritize my changes over the origin master. However it's failing, Is there a mistake in my code?

```
git clone https://github.com/production public_code
cd public_code
git remote add priv https://gitlab.com/tmv/development
git merge -Xours priv/dev origin/master
```

Output

```
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "force merge". What error do you get when these commands fail?

Comment: Understood, changed the description

Comment: And what do you mean by "its failing"? What happens after you run these commands?

Comment: Output is Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: The problem is you are merging two remote tracking branches into your local master. I think this isn't what you want.

Comment: the code in the answer works for different remotes as well?

Comment: The key here is that you cannot merge remote branches directly. Instead, you merge local copies of those branches and then push to the remote branch.

Comment: I tried to do a `fetch` for the remote. Nothing seems to enable me to merge them locally as well, without manual commit and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just cloned the one repo, you only need to do a regular merge:

```
git clone https://github.com/production public_code
cd public_code
git remote add priv https://gitlab.com/tmv/development
git merge -Xtheirs priv/dev
git push origin HEAD
```

After cloning, the master branch will already be checked out, and you will already have the latest in master.

Comment: Except that it should be `-Xtheirs` because `priv/dev` should take precedence.

Comment: @j6t Then with that change, Greg's answer should give what you want. However I want to caution about blindly accepting one side or the other. Instead, you should visually inspect the merge conflicts and accept what is appropriate, possibly editing to make sure the code does what it is supposed to. Blindly accepting `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs` is a quick path to bugs.

Comment: @j6t: missed that little bit. Answer updated.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You are absolutely right. It is obvious from the question, though, that the OP wants to take the risk.

Comment: @j6t My bad...I thought you were the OP.

Answer (score 1):

`git merge` merges the current local branch with any branches that you give at the command line. You cannot really merge upstream branches. So in your example, you are merging both `priv/dev` and `origin/master` in to the local `master` branch. Instead, you need to merge local copies of those branches and then push the final result to the upstream repo:

```
git clone <repo URL>
cd <repo dir>
git checkout <branch you want to merge into>
git merge <branch you want to merge>
git push
```